# Insert Description Text to Drupal User Registration Form

Tags: drupal, forms, profile, categories

I am using the profile module and have several categories for different fields. I want to add a small bit of text to the top of one of the categories saying what the category is for. The information would be displayed when a new user registered. Basically I want to tell users to only fill out a category on certain conditions. Can anyone tell me how I could do this? I'm guessing I could use hook_form_alter(), but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [create your own module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) and implement hook_form_alter like you mentioned.

In a nutshell:

- Use print_r($form) in hook_form_alter to look through what you'll need to edit
- A category will have a #type => 'fieldset' and #title => 'What you named your category'
- Remove print_r and add $form['categoryname']['#description'] = 'My description here!';

You may have to update your module's "weight" as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424183/drupal-cck-date-field-question/3425106#3425106) (replacing CCK with Profile).

Answer (score 0):

As [Chris Ridenour alluded to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439949/insert-description-text-to-drupal-user-registration-form/3443504#3443504), you can do this with [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'user_profile_form') {
    // Change personal to the name of the category.
    $form['personal']['#description'] = t('This is a description of your personal information.');
  }
}
```

In this example, it adds a description to the *personal* category on the user profile form.

You can read more about what types of things you can modify in the [Forms API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6). If you have the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module installed, `dsm($form)` within your `hook_form_alter()` will pretty-print the form structure to give you an idea of what's available to alter.